# Code 124 (Invalid access token) received for Zoom API calls using JWT

Tags: php, jwt, zoom-sdk

When using either dynamically created JWT tokens, or even hard-copying the one provided from the App Marketplace for my app, my API requests always fail due to an ‘invalid access token’.

I am currently working on the Meetings endpoint, specifically trying to create a meeting. The endpoint is: https://eu01api-www4local.zoom.us/v2/users/me/meetings (using the GDPR compliant EU base URL).

My cURL request looks like this:

```
$body = json_encode($body);

$arr = [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => $this->timeout,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "authorization: Bearer " . $this->generate_JWT(),
        "content-type: application/json"
    ],
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $body
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $arr);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$err = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

(`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` is set to false here, as I'm testing from localhost.)

The `generate_JWT` function looks like this:

```
private function generate_JWT()
{
    $payload = [
        "iss" => self::ZOOM_API_SECRET,
        "exp" => time() + $this->timeout,
    ];
    return JWT::encode($payload, self::ZOOM_API_KEY, 'HS256');
}
```

... using the [Firebase\JWT\JWT](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) class for encoding.

The 'app' itself is activated and live on the account, set as JWT type, with no intent to publish, and is 'Account level'.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint described in the Documentation for GDPR compliant EU users is not, in fact, operable - at least for this type of work. The original .us base URL must be used.